# Finding the full output path for a VRay render setting in Maya using Python?

Tags: python, render, layer, maya

I am trying to write a plugin that works with the most recently rendered preview image in Maya. I mostly write tools and pipelines around Houdini, Nuke, and C4D, so moving around Maya has been somewhat difficult.

I need to be able to find the full output path for the currently active render setting. In most cases our artists render using VRay, however some do use software and mentalray, so I need to figure out which I am using first and foremost, then find the path, unless I am able to simply call the path to the currently active layer.

So far I am able to find and use most other values throughout the render settings, however the full output path to the image I am going to render for anything other than the default layer has evaded me.

Since I have been unable to find a variable holding that value, I have been trying to build the path from what I am able to find, such as the path to the current images dir for the project and the "File Name Prefix". There I run into the issue of the artists calling the render variables for their output; Scene, Layer, and such. I know how to find a few of them through other methods, so I may be able to translate if needed, but I feel there has to be a way to call their values and I simply do not know it.

TL;DR:

Looking for a way to find the full path for the currently active render layer, something like renderSettings(fullpath=True) but that actually returns a.

OR

Looking for a way to call the render variables, so once I find that the "File Name Prefix" is Scene/Layer/Scene I can translate to find the full path.

TIA!

Answer (score -1):

Maya typically deposits images into the images directory of the current workspace.  You can find the root of the project tree and the image directory in python using:

```
 import os
 import maya.cmds as cmds
 workspace_root = cmds.workspace(q=True, dir=True)
 images_dir = cmds.workspace("image", q=True, fre=True).strip()
 file_name = cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix') or       os.path.basename(cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)) or "untitled"
 # defaultRenderGlobals is a node that exists in the scene which holds the render settings
 # you get the prefix with a standard getAttr

 file_location = os.path.join(workspace_root, images_dir, file_name).replace("\\", "/")
```

Deriving the file extension is a little trickier, but [Brian Ewert's website](http://ewertb.soundlinker.com/mel/mel.065.php) has the trick for figuring it out in mel, it's easy to translate to python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those are the values I am able to derive so far. The tricky part has been finding out what layer we are in for when artists use something like:

$MayaProj/images/SceneName/LayerName/SceneName.Frame.ext

Comment: the layers in the scene are renderLayer nodes; you can get those with cmds.ls(type='renderLayer').  It might be an easier job for you if you write your own front end and ask the artists for the info you need then make sure you manually set up the render the way you want - it's tough to infer it from the render commands